# legumes, pulses, or some thing else?

Tags: expressions, food

Suppose I've bought me some chickpeas and lentils, boiled them and have started chowing down.

Would you say I'm "eating legumes"? "eating pulses"? Something else?

Would your answer change if I added peanuts, beans, lupins etc.?

Comment: It's all a matter of the terminology that is idiomatic in your context.  "Pulses", while not commonly used, is known and used in some circles.  But more often the meal would be described as "eating chickpeas and lentils" or some such.

Comment: Indeed, nothing is more local and ununiversal as food terms. There are places where you'd just say you were eating dal, or beans, or frijol. Or any other names.

Comment: I wish people would not say (or write) "chow down".

Comment: For Passover, I made a dish that's mostly apricots, dates and almonds (a Sephardi charoset). I can imagine someone eating this dish saying, "I'm eating drupes" - and I can imagine everyone else rolling their eyes painfully. Likewise, "eating pulses/legumes" is *possible*, it's meaningful, but it would sound pretty affected or stilted.

Comment: At least in the UK, this type of food is referred to as _pulses_ in advice about healthy eating. _Legumes_ is more of a botanical term.

Comment: @KateBunting: So, I might see a "pulse" or "pulses" section in a supermarket?

Comment: The online supermarkets seem to have categories labelled 'Beans and pulses' or similar. See also https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/eat-well/beans-and-pulses-nutrition/